# How to remove .txt on a .zshrc file using Z shell on a mac?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I had to edit my .zshrc file and it was locked, so essentially created a copy, then edited and deleted the original .zshrc file. I have renamed my '.zshrc copy' file to just '.zshrc' however when I ls -a it shows as .zshrc.txt

How do I remove the .txt end?

Comment: How did you rename it? Sounds like the file was originally named `.zshrc copy.txt`, and you somehow only remove the ` copy` from the name. (Related: how did you copy the file, and what editor did you use to save the edited copy? Sounds like the editor added an implicit `.txt` to the file name, and the Finder by default does not show file extensions.)

Comment: @chepner when i renamed it it only had this on the edit field ' zshrc copy' so i only back spaced the 'copy' part. for the editor I used the default one from mac, I am also new to mac.

Comment: So you renamed it in the Finder? I would strongly recommend enabling the "Show all file name extensions" in the Advanced tab of Finder -> Preferences so you can see the "real" file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the file using the mv command to remove the .txt extension

```
cd ~
cp .zshrc backup_zshrc
mv .zshrc.txt .zshrc
```

overwrite it if it already exists

Comment: Seems highly unlikely that someone will need `sudo` to rename their own shell configuration files.